# load a well log data that is in a .log file format instead of LAS format

Tags: python, logging, ascii, las

I've a well log data I'm trying to work on, some of the files are in the usual LAS file format which I've been able to work with but other files are in .log file format. Pls, I would appreciate if there is someone with same problems before and how it was worked on

Comment: So I happen to know what a well log is. But you should not expect anyone on this site to know what you mean by "well log". I also know that they come in a variety of formats, so even I can't help you. Show data as text (not a screen shot), show what you've tried. Show what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have well log files, some are in .log file extension and some are in the usual las file..I've been able to load the las files using lasio and welly libraries but I've been able to process the .log files